# Why isn't docker reusing docker-compose's cache layers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is a cut-down example of a problem I'm having with a bigger Dockerfile.

Here's a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest AS base
COPY docker-compose.yml /tmp/docker-compose.yml
RUN touch /tmp/foo
```

Here's a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
```

What I expect is that `docker build` will be able to reuse the cached layers that `docker-compose` builds.  What I see when I run `docker-compose build web` is:

```
  $ docker-compose build web
Building web
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:latest AS base
 ---> f70734b6a266
Step 2/3 : COPY docker-compose.yml /tmp/docker-compose.yml
 ---> 764c54eb3dd4
Step 3/3 : RUN touch /tmp/foo
 ---> Running in 77bdf96af899
Removing intermediate container 77bdf96af899
 ---> 7d8197f7004f

Successfully built 7d8197f7004f
Successfully tagged docker-compose-caching_web:latest
```

If I re-run `docker-compose build web`, I get:

```
...
Step 2/3 : COPY docker-compose.yml /tmp/docker-compose.yml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 764c54eb3dd4
...
```

So it's clearly able to cache the layer with the file in it.  However, when I run `docker build .`, here's the output I see:

```
  $ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:latest AS base
 ---> f70734b6a266
Step 2/3 : COPY docker-compose.yml /tmp/docker-compose.yml
 ---> e8679333ba0d
Step 3/3 : RUN touch /tmp/foo
 ---> Running in af26cc65312d
Removing intermediate container af26cc65312d
 ---> 186c8341ee96
Successfully built 186c8341ee96
```

Note step 2 didn't come from the cache.  Why not?  Or, more importantly, how can I ensure that it does without using `--cache-from`?

The problem this causes is that after this step in my bigger Dockerfile that I'm not showing, there's a honking great `RUN` command that takes an age to run.  How can I get `docker build` and `docker-compose build` to share cache layers?

(Docker Desktop v 2.3.0.2 (45183) on OS X 10.14.6 for those playing along at home)

Comment: What about `sudo docker-compose up --build`
Are you sure there are no a single change in your `Dockerfile` each time these `build` ran?\

Answer (score 5):

With [Docker-compose 1.25+ (Dec. 2019)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1250), try and use:

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 docker-compose build
```

That is what is needed to enable the docker-cli, instead of the own internal docker-compose build.

See also  "[Faster builds in Docker Compose 1.25.1 thanks to BuildKit Support](https://www.docker.com/blog/faster-builds-in-compose-thanks-to-buildkit-support/)".
But be aware of [docker-compose issue 7336](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7336), when using it with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` (in addition of `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1`)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a known issue. For reasons I don't entirely understand, hashes generated by `docker compose build` are different from those generated by `docker build`.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/883